# Concatenar data em PHP para inserir no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, data

Bom dia, a minha dúvida consiste no método de concatenação e de criação de um Datetime para inserir numa base de dados.

Tendo as variáveis:

```
$dia = '2018-04-11';
$hora = '09:36';
```

O formato desejado é: `AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`
Como faço para juntar e enviar estes dados para a BD?

Exemplo do que eu pensei:

```
 INSERT INTO nome_tabela (data_inicio) VALUES concat(data_inicio(Datetime?($dia,$hora))) ??
```

Têm como ajudar a compor e esclarecer-me como criar o registo com essa data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por exemplo:

```
$dia = '2018-04-11';
$hora = '09:36';

$datahora = $dia . ' ' . $hora . ':00';
//                  ^              ^--- segundos opcionais no final
//                  '--- espaço entre as partes

$sql = "INSERT INTO nome_tabela (data_inicio) VALUES '$datahora';";
```

Para aprendizado apenas, se quiser o `CONCAT`:

```
$dia = '2018-04-11';
$hora = '09:36';

$sql = "INSERT INTO nome_tabela (data_inicio) VALUES CONCAT('$data', ' ', '$hora', ':00')";
```

Note que nem precisa do `:00` no final, só pus pra ilustrar. O importante é respeitar o formato ISO, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, preenchendo da esquerda para a direita.

Isto posto, considere não trabalhar com *strings* desta forma na aplicação. Tente achar um formato numérico que atenda melhor, para evitar ter que fazer operações muito complexas com os dados.

Por exemplo, datas e horas com precisão de segundos podem ser armazenadas em inteiros, se usar o formato POSIX (até 2038), e se quiser mais tempo, basta usar um offset (por exemplo, tomar por base o número de segundos desde o ano 2010).

Alternativamente, o PHP tem classes para data e hora, mas não justifica o custo adicional para usos simples como esse seu, pois é só mais código e processamento para resultar na mesma coisa:

```
$dia = '2018-04-11';
$hora = '09:36';

$dateobject = new DateTime( $dia . ' ' . $hora );

// só faz sentido usar isso se for processar a data
// de maneira complexa antes de usar

$datahora = $dateobject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO nome_tabela (data_inicio) VALUES '$datahora';";
```